# OS X: How do I alter preferences for the login window?

Tags: macos

In particular, I want to set the mouse tracking speed. But I'd rather have a generic answer.

I don't need access to the System Preferences UI, I'm fine with using `defaults`.

I guess Login Window runs as root, right? What preferences files are looked up for it?

#### update

I had some partial luck with:

```
sudo -s
cp ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist          /Library/Preferences/
cp ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist          /private/var/root/Library/Preferences/
cp ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.*.plist /private/var/root/Library/Preferences/ByHost/
```

By which I mean, I was able to notice the following effects:

- the color scheme switched to graphite. (and the button is still blue #applefail LOL)
- the display color profile is now correct in the login window (yay)

But no luck with fixing the mouse tracking.

Comment: I want "Tap to click" and "tab between all controls" enabled.

Comment: I guess we can just copy our entire .GlobalPreferences.plist over the root's. Which I don't know where is.

Comment: How about /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist ?

Comment: Nop, that doesn't affect the login window.

Comment: More interestingly, changing the one in `/private/var/root/Library/Preferences/` didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the values in `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHIDMouse.plist`. For example, tracking speed looks to be set up by one of these `PreferenceDefaults` values:

```
<key>ScrollH</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>ScrollS</key>
<integer>4</integer>
<key>ScrollSSize</key>
<integer>30</integer>
<key>ScrollV</key>
<integer>1</integer>
```